# Yii2: Assign and remove items via ajax like in RBAC routes assignment

Tags: ajax, yii2

I need assistance. In Yii2 RBAC module, there is a part in the module when adding routes and removing them whereby it is done via selecting the routes and clicking on the button which moves them to the right, or remove button that moves them to the left via ajax. I have tried to search online but I guess I don't have the right description to help me get better results. I believe there must be an extension for achieving this. Below is the screenshot of what exactly I mean. I want to implement this in some part of my system but I don't know what to simply search on the internet so as to get the clue.[image: Routes Screenshot]
Any clue to what I should look for or an extension that will assist me achieve this is welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try for this some of jquery plugins. Maybe this one http://loudev.com/ or https://github.com/crlcu/multiselect

Comment: Thank you @Anastasia. I will have a look at these two.